# Is there only a finite number of non-equivalent formulas in the predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

My intuition says: Yes of course. Let's say that we have a finite signature and just k many quantifiers and no free variables.
Therefore I tried to prove it by converting it into the prenex form and making an combinatorial argument over the amount of possible quantifier prefixes, but that didn't work out. Afterwards I tried to convert it to a propositional formula, but then I have to rely on a structure. (But I know that there are just a finite number of non-equivalent formulas in the propositional logic over a static set of variables.)
Could anyone provide me with an approach to that problem?

Comment: Are you talking about a predicate logic with a finite number of variables?

Comment: Yes, since we have no free variables and just k many quantifiers (at most), we also have at most k many variables.

Comment: @multiplex It's worth noting that we usually *don't* place any restriction on the number of quantifiers allowed ...

Comment: @Noah Schweber But when we remove the restriction the set of all formulas in the predicate logic does instantly become infinitely huge, right? Just as Stefan Meske pointed out.

Comment: @multiplex Yup. My point was just that you seemed to implicitly assume that we're only allowed a bounded number of quantifiers in predicate logic, and that's not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are infinitely many non-equivalent formulas in predicate logic. A very simple example is $(\phi_n \mid n < \omega)$ with
$$
\phi_n = \exists v_1 \exists v_2 \ldots \exists v_n \colon \bigwedge_{i < j \le n} v_i \neq v_j. 
$$

$\phi_n$ is true in a given model (in the empty language) iff that model has at least $n$ elements.

---

The body of your post appears to ask a different question from its title: Given a finite signature. How many non-equivalent sentences (formulas with no free variables) with at most $k$ quantifiers are there?

If your signature contains a constant symbol $f$ and a $2$-ary relation symbol $\prec$, consider
$$
\phi_n \equiv \forall x \exists y \underbrace{f \circ f \circ \ldots \circ f}_{n \text{-times}}(x) \prec y.$$

The sequence $(\phi_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ is pairwise non-equivalent as can be seen by looking at the structure $(\{1, 2, \ldots, n \}, f, \prec)$, where $\prec = < \restriction \{1,2, \ldots, n \}$ and
$$
f(i) = \begin{cases}
i +1 & \text{, if } i < n, \\
n & \text{, otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Hence the answer to your question, in general, is: No, even under those restrictions there can be infintely many non-equivalent first order formulas.

Comment: He did say there is a bound on the number of quantifiers.

Comment: Yes exactly, since we are pretty much bounded by the number of quantifiers, variables and the size of the signature, I would still say that it is finite.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, I didn't catch that on my first read (since I considered the question in the title of OP's post). If my answer doesn't seem relevant, I'd be happy to remove it.

Comment: @Stefan Meske Sorry for being unclear in the question. How would you make it more specific? Should I mention the restrictions directly in the question? (Although it becomes a beast of a question)

Comment: I think the question is fine -- the title is a bit misleading, though.

Comment: @multiplex In case you've already seen the previous edit of my answer: My argument didn't work. In order to form equivalent prenex normal forms we need to rename variables which we can't do...

Comment: What you say about "cheating" isn't right. There is nothing wrong with nesting application of a function symbol any number of times. $f(x) < y, f(f(x)) < y, f(f(f(x))) < y, \ldots$ are all perfectly good formulas.

Comment: @RobArthan Oh, you are right. I'm pretty happy about that since it simplifies the answer significantly ;-)

Comment: @multiplex You should take a look at Rob's comment and my updated answer.

Comment: In the same vein as Rob's comment, if you have a constant symbol $a$, do you need any variables or quantifiers? ($f(a) \prec a$, $f(f(a)) \prec a$, etc.)

Comment: @FabioSomenzi If you have two constant symbols, you can do the same thing without any variables. Assign one constant to $1$ (in my example) and the other to $n$.

Comment: Agreed.  I edited my comment to clarify that $a$ is the constant symbol.

Comment: Incidentally, it may be worth noting that it is a well-known fact that the Herbrand universe is infinite if the signature contains at least a function symbol with positive arity.

Comment: That's a really interesting proof. That even holds true, when we make the restrictions stronger and just allow certain types of signatures e.g. consisting just of relations or functions (since functions are relations, which are nestable). Am I right on this one?

Comment: @multiplex Yes - all you need is one relation symbol (then you can code both the function and the order via a definable pairing function).